# Installing MySQL 5.1 on Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion)

Tags: mysql, osx-lion

I am trying to install MySQL 5.1. I am on Lion, and when I remove all files associated with MySQL on my machine it still tells me that I have a newer version installed when I try to install it from the DMG file.

Has anyone successfully installed MySQL 5.1 on Lion?

I found [a solution using Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788381/getting-cant-connect-through-socket-tmp-mysql-when-installing-mysql-on-ma/5140849#5140849):

1. Completely remove MySQL from your system (just in case)

   ```
   sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
   sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
   sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
   sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
   vim /etc/hostconfig and removed the line MYSQLCOM=-YES-
   rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
   sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
   sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
   sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.*
   ```

   Source:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436425/how-do-you-uninstall-mysql-from-mac-os-x
2. Install homebrew

   ```
   /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731)"
   ```

   Source: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation
3. Install MySQL 5.1 via brew

   ```
   brew install mysql51
   ```

   if that doesn't work, do this:

   ```
   brew install https://raw.github.com/adamv/homebrew-alt/master/versions/mysql51.rb
   ```

   Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359131/brew-install-mysql-on-mac-os/6399627#6399627
4. Make MySQL Work

   1. Create mysql.sock file

      ```
      touch /tmp/mysql.sock
      ```
   2. Install MySQL default tables

      ```
      /usr/local/Cellar/mysql51/5.1.58/bin/mysql_install_db
      ```

      ...or your path

Comment: go to terminal and try running this: which mysql ! try as sudo and as normal user!

Comment: i couldn't install mysql 5.1=)

Comment: If you're still reading this: it would be great if you reposted your edit as a standalone answer, so you can accept it. (And maybe get some upvotes too; be sure to use `@arjan` if you're replying! `;-)`)

Comment: When I uninstalled MySQL from my OSX system, the daemon was still in memory, and hence the file was still "there". Make sure you use `launchctl` to kill/unload it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you [tried this](http://akrabat.com/php/setting-up-php-mysql-on-os-x-10-7-lion/).

Download the 64-bit DMG version of MySQL 5.1.x (or 5.5.x) for Mac OS X 10.6 from the official MySQL site and install the package, the startup item and the preference pane.

Add `/usr/local/mysql/bin` to the path:

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

And add:

```
export PATH=~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
export EDITOR=vim
```

At the top of file. (Note that we set EDITOR whilst we are here so that svn is happy!)

Set up MySQL root password:

```
mysqladmin -u root password {new-password}
mysqladmin -u root -p{new-password} -h localhost password {new-password}
mysqladmin -u root -p{new-password} reload
```

Clear the history file by typing history -c so that {new-password} isn't in plain text on the disk.

Now ensure that the `mysql.sock` file can be found by PHP:
Ensure that MySQL is running

```
sudo mkdir /var/mysql
sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Yes. Installing MySQL5.1 dmg version doesn't work. It says that I have a newer version of MySQL installed on my machine, even though I have completely wiped it off my machine with the instructions found on stackoverflow.

I actually found a solution, going to post it in case someone runs into the same problem.